# Curly braces making for loop run only once?

Tags: java, c++, c

Let's say I have a pseudocode and sum = 3

```
for i = (1 to 3)
    sum = sum + i
    return sum
```

This returns 9 because 3+1=4, 4+2=6, 6+3=9

---

But when doing this

```
for i = (1 to 3) {
    sum = sum + i
    return sum
}
```

Sum returned is 4?
Why does the curly braces somehow make the for loop run only once?

Comment: Which pseudocode compiler are you using?

Comment: Becase loop terminated for first iteration

Comment: @Martin James it's a quiz, I got it wrong so..

Comment: @TruthSeeker Is this a property of the curly braces? It only run for loop once?

Comment: Without the curly braces only the first line after the `for` is part of the loop body. The curly braces makes all those lines inside the braces part of the loop body.

Comment: Curly braces, in this case (assuming a C/C++-like pseudocode) combine multiple statements (those inside the braces) into a single, *compound* statement. The body of a `for` loop actually comprises *one* statement - whether that be simple or compound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation of the first loop is misleading. Unroll both and it will be apparent what's going on:

```
sum = sum + 1
sum = sum + 2
sum = sum + 3
return sum
```

This one adds 6 to `sum` and then returns it.

```
sum = sum + 1
return sum
sum = sum + 2
return sum
sum = sum + 3
return sum
```

This one adds 1 to `sum` and then returns it. A `return` statement ends execution of the function (even if there's more statements after it, or it's inside a loop).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following C code:

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; ++i)
   sum = sum + i;
   return sum;
```

Then you have a misleading way of writing

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; ++i)
   sum = sum + i;

return sum;
```

That's because the above snippets are both equivalent to the following:

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; ++i) {
   sum = sum + i;
}

return sum;
```

The body of a `for` loop is either a single statement or a block. Most languages don't consider indentation level to be significant. (Python is a notable exception.)

In contrast, the following executes the `return` each pass of the loop instead of after the loop is complete:

```
for (int i=1; i<=3; ++i) {
   sum = sum + i;
   return sum;
}
```

Well, it'll never reach the second pass of the loop, of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
    sum = sum + i
    return sum
```

run `sum = sum + i` 3 times. Then execute `return sum`, cause if loop construction has no braces it will run only one next operation.

Here

```
for i = (1 to 3) {
    sum = sum + i
    return sum
}
```

every loop iteration will try to execute `return sum` and only first iteration will really execute this. Next iteraions will not be executed cause `return` will break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you are including a return statement into the body of the for loop, and thus returning on the first iteration.  In the first example, only the addition/assignment statement is executed in your loop and then the result returned.